Java Regular Expression not working for this special use case
The following is my code:
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pageText = "Other Strings 9.5.1 My Other Strings";
        String pageText2 = "Other Strings 9.3.1.1.1 My Other Strings";
        Pattern anyServicePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.){2}[0-9]\\s+[a-zA-Z]+");
        Matcher anyServiceMatcher = anyServicePattern.matcher(pageText);
        if (anyServiceMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
        
        Matcher anyServiceMatcher2 = anyServicePattern.matcher(pageText2);
        if (anyServiceMatcher2.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}

It prints:
Found
Found
I want it to print
Found
Not Found
i.e. I want the regular expression should match the pattern <whatever characters><any number><dot><any number><dot><any number><single or double space><whatever characters> 
I tried many combinations, but to my high surprise couldn't crack it. What is the correct expression?
Here is the jdoodle link: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/14IW

Use (?<!\d\.)(?:\d+\.){2}[0-9]\s+[a-zA-Z]+ as regex

explanation: it is finding 1.1.1 My in the second example - which is correct according to <whatever characters><any number><dot><any number><dot><any number><single or double space><whatever characters> unless <whatever characters> does not include spaces, dots, and digits

Thanks to the other answers prior to answering my own question. Finally I went with the following regular  expression:
Pattern anyServicePattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z\\s]+((\\d+\\.){2}\\d+){1}\\s+[a-zA-Z]+");  

I found it easy for others to understand and it solved some other corner cases like "Other String9.3.1 My Other Strings"

You can simply use a pattern with an space (\s) on the left, such as (?i)\\s((?:\\d+\\.){2}\\d+)\\s+[a-z]:
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pageText = "Other Strings 9.5.1 My Other Strings";
        String pageText2 = "Other Strings 9.3.1.1.1 My Other Strings";
        Pattern anyServicePattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\s((?:\\d+\\.){2}\\d+)\\s+[a-z]");
        Matcher anyServiceMatcher = anyServicePattern.matcher(pageText);
        if (anyServiceMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }

        Matcher anyServiceMatcher2 = anyServicePattern.matcher(pageText2);
        if (anyServiceMatcher2.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}

Prints
Found
Not Found


Details:

(?i): insensitive flag.
\\s: one space before the the version.
((?:\\d+\\.){2}\\d+): a capture group which matches the versions with one or more digits (e.g., 1.121115.1, 121.1233.1121, ... 1212.1244.91221.
\\s+[a-z]: one or more spaces and a letter on the right side.


The problem with your regex is that for the second case, it just matches "1.1.1 My Other Strings" because your first "whatever character" also includes the "9.3." from the second text.
So to meet your expectations I would suggest one of those two options:

match a space before your number/dot combination
add a zero-with negative lookbehind

The space match would be: \s(\d+\.){2}\d\s+[a-zA-Z]+
The zero-with negative lookbehind variant: (?!<\d\.)(\d+\.){2}\d\s+[a-zA-Z]+
Please note that I didn't escape the escape characters so you can test the regular expressions also elsewhere (like regex101.com) and also note that I replaced your last part with the character class for digit \d as you used that before.
There are also other potential problems with your pattern - I didn't fix them but want to give you a heads up:

This pattern will not directly match your description since you wrote it should match "whatever character" first, but the match will start only after that part but include the final "whatever character" part.

The final "whatever character" part is not "whatever character" as you wrote it - it matches only upper and lower case letters from a-z. Not even spaces included in the middle.


Depending whether you need to just find lines that match or want to actually work with the found part, you will have to adjust your pattern further, but since you didn't specify your needs in more detail, this should be asked with  another question - if necessary at all.

Let's first see what the pattern is matching:

(\d+\.) => a group consisting of any number followed by a dot
{2} => match the preceding group twice
[0-9] => any digit between 0-9
\s+ => one or more white spaces
[a-zA-Z] => any upper case or lowercase letter of the alphabet

Apply that to your first string Other Strings 9.5.1 My Other Strings, a match would be found in 9.5.1 My. Now, apply that to your first string Other Strings 9.3.1.1.1 My Other Strings, a match would be found in 1.1.1 My. That's why you are getting found in both cases. Note you are not matching the whole string in any of the above cases.
Solution:
If you number sequence always start with a space add \s at the beginning of the pattern.
\s(\\d+\\.){2}[0-9]\\s+[a-zA-Z]+

If space before number sequence is not guaranteed, make sure the pattern is not preceded by any number followed by a dot
(?<!\\d\\.)(\\d+\\.){2}[0-9]\\s+[a-zA-Z]+

(?<!\\d\\.) represents a zero-width negative lookbehind. In short it asserts that the pattern \d\. does not match.
Note
There are several issue with you pattern requirement and your regular expression. (Also pointed out by others)

Your regular expression does not match the whole required pattern, only a section of it.
You said <any number><dot><any number><dot><any number> but your regular expression would only match <any number><dot><any number><dot><any digit>. So, it won't match 2.5.12. Use [0-9]+ or \\d+ if you wish to match any number.
You said <single or double space> but your regular expression would also match more than two spaces after the last digit. To match one or two spaces use \\s{1,2} instead of \\s+
What does  mean? Is it alphanumeric character/white spaces/newlines? Your regular expression only matching upper and lower case letters.

